# Android browser redirecting malware sites

Tags: malware

I was redirected to appsliu, onclickads and some other sites which were reffered as malware when I was surfing the internet using android browserd on my Xperia Z1. I tried clearing data along with cache in flight mode and also formatting my phone. This happened on my brother's phone chrome too. Any suggestion to clear out this problem? I heard that it is something related to super cookies and how can I remove it from my phone? Your replies are highly appreciated. ☺

Comment: Your phone is perfectly fine. It's just the online pop-up ads which redirect you to malware sites or to an app page. Just install Firefox and add AdBlock Plus to it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the problem inside your phone or your software. Its something that webscripts are responsible for. Many webpages create automatic redirecting ad popups.

There are two ways to deal with this->

1) To use [AdBlock](https://adblockplus.org/android-install) Plus or similar like [MANI](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/68295/mani) said. Though on personal note, I haven't really been able to get any such AdBlocking apps to work properly on Android. But again, that could be just me doing something wrong perhaps.

2) Change your DNS. You can use alternative Domain Name Server such as [Open DNS](https://www.opendns.com/) or [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or any other alternative you prefer. This works by changing your lookup for an ad-server which points to your local machine, hence basically preventing them to do anything to your PC. Additionally, many DNS servers are configured to block access to domains or hostnames which are responsible for such ads.

By the way, here's Google DNS and Open DNS in case you want to use:

```
Google DNS    
DNS 1 – 8.8.8.8
DNS 2 – 8.8.4.4

OpenDNS    
DNS 1 – 208.67.222.222
DNS 2 – 208.67.220.220
```

Also, you do not need to worry about malware. Malware wont affect your android device unless you manually install a malware infected app :)

Comment: Fantastic answer! Care to also include how to set the DNS on an Android?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow you can download an application named DNSset which can also change the cell data to change the dns for phone. This at least works for my phone

Comment: Thanks sir jaskaranbir. It works after I changed my dns to google's. It is not redirecting to those sites anymore however it redirects me to play store but it bugs me less. Technically it solved my problem as redirection to play store is still managable for me. As for mozilla firefox with adblock add on, I have not tried it yet but will tell you the result after trying it.

Comment: Your welcome, glad you were able to sort out (even if at some extend). On side note, you can go to settings-> apps -> play store and "clear defaults" for it. This way instead of redirecting you to store, the webpage will instead ask the app to use for redirecting you which you can easily cancel and hence will not be redirected. The downside is that everytime you open a play store link using browser, it will still ask to use browser or play store market to go to that link.

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh no prob dude. The problem now occurs again and I found out that requesting desktop site will settle the problem. Solution that you suggested once worked but they are not working already

Answer (score 0):

Usually  it has nothing to do with your phone . its because cache server on your ISP. just call them and ask them to activate DNS poison detection.