# Popup virus warning received from ninaxu.com

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

Recently started receiving a popup overlay screen from ninaxu.com - Google logo appears behind the overlay screen. Says my Android has 13 virus most likely received from visiting porn sites, however, I have never sought out porn sites (not judging others from visiting those sites, but I wouldn't introduce my phone to such a risk).  Anyway, a 2-min count down appears saying the SIM card would be damaged if Googles' antivirus isn't installed.  I can't back out when this popup occurs and have to reboot my phone.  The first instance of this popup occurred when I clicked on a link from my email subscription to "Mutts."  I ran and regularly run, AVG and no virus were detected.  Anyone else encounter this problem?  Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It's just a scareware popup by suspicious websites/ads. If you didn't follow the link on that popup, you're clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell this is nothing but a fake (trying to make you take the bait) by just some basic rules:

- a countdown: "If you don't act within 2 min, the virus will X". Interesting: How do they know that will happen in exactly 2 min? Nothing but panicking you.
- the SIM card would be damaged: nonsense. Never heard any malware attacks the SIM card. Or the battery, which those messages often claim as well.
- "Google's antivirus": Apart from the fact that there is no such app, Google definitely wouldn't chose an approach like that.
- "13 virus": *LOL* Name a single Android ***virus*** (hint: there is none. Especially not 13. The term "virus" is completely mis-used on the Android platform, most obviously either as a "scare word" or because people are used to that kind of "software" from their Windows machine. True, there's *malware* – but no virus. Read the [Wikipedia article on Computer Virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus) on this, and take a special close look at the end of the first paragraph: "the defining characteristic of viruses is that they are ***self-replicating*** computer programs which ***install themselves without user consent***" (emphasis mine). Malware on Android is usually installed by the user himself)

So after explaining the background, I can only agree with Andrew:

> It's just a scareware popup by suspicious websites/ads. If you didn't follow the link on that popup, you're clean.

And you usually get out of that by pressing the <kbd>back</kbd> button multiple times, closing the relevant browser tab, or closing the browser altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - anyway to keep that annoying popup from popping up?

Comment: Except for not visiting the website that opens it? Unfortunately not, @LittleRedShoes – unless rooting and an effective ad blocker count as options.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, get something like that at least once a month. Close the website whenever this appears and reload it. Today I've got the message that I've been selected to maybe win an iPhone or Samsung, if I take part in a Telekom survey. All with the typical magenta Telekom logo.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [my question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114360/android-browser-redirecting-malware-sites) and the answer for my question. It worked for me, and one more thing, I found out that sometimes if you request desktop site, the popup or redirect will not happen. (which means that those redirect will only happen if I was using mobile site, at least it was like this in my case)

Hope it helps =)